# Trying to make a bot to buy the ps5

Tags: python, selenium

So i am trying to pre-order the latest PS5 (during the sale )for which i thought to write a python script bot(Newbie to python)  .I managed to write the below for another product .However the total time taken till i reach the final transaction page is just over 1 min ,and that too when the server is not loaded .

Is there anything i can do make the transaction run faster till the last page under 30 secs if possible ?

And since i am a newbie trying to learn from automate the boring stuff from python  ,Plese suggest some what improvements can i make on my code ?

Also is there a possible way to run this headless till i enter my otp to confirm the transaction its basically the last page for which i am not using headless mode?
...

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#op.add_argument('headless')
op.add_argument('disable-infobars')
op.add_argument('disable-extensions')
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
url ='https://www.flipkart.com/latibule-scratch-remover-wax/p/itm251fceb778c9f?pid=SCAG2W9BU2GEJFUW&lid=LSTSCAG2W9BU2GEJFUWHKPRKY&marketplace=FLIPKART&q=car+scratch+remover&store=1mt%2Fuhg%2Fzfb%2F2wf&srno=s_1_2&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_8_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_8_na_na_na&fm=SEARCH&iid=3cbc56ce-4032-4ad3-9f8c-f58e3572b637.SCAG2W9BU2GEJFUW.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&ssid=duj7dx9q340000001622962739970&qH=7307be34aace13e8'
browser=webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\FAST\Python\3.7.0\chromedriver.exe',options=op)
browser.get(url)
i=0
while True: 
    try: 
        element = WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(
            #EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._2KpZ6l._2U9uOA.ihZ75k._3AWRsL"))
        )
        break
    except: 
       # print('element not found/not clickable')
        continue
print('element found')
try:
    while (element.is_enabled()):
        element.click()
except:

    print(url)
    flag=1
    while(browser.current_url):
        try:
           if (flag ==1):
                
                elem =browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input._17N0em')
                while(not elem.get_attribute('value')):                
                    elem.send_keys('8xxxxxxxxx')
                    elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                    flag=2
                    
           elif (flag==2):
                elem =browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=password]')
                while(not elem.get_attribute('value')):
                        elem.send_keys('111@1234')
                        time.sleep(2)
                        elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                        flag=3

           elif(flag==3):       
                elem =browser.find_element_by_id('to-payment')
                while( elem is None):
                    continue
                elem.click()
                flag=4
                

           elif(flag==4):        
                elem =browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input._1w3ZZo._2mFmU7')
                while( elem is None):
                    continue
                elem.send_keys('xxx')
                elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                flag= 5
                
           elif (flag==5):
               break
    

        except:
            continue
    print('end')
    print(url)
    print(browser.current_url)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things I would make it other.
1)

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._2KpZ6l._2U9uOA.ihZ75k._3AWRsL"))
```

If that element is normally expected to appear there you should use much longer timeout. Since this is not a kind of sleep, Selenium will continue exactly on the moment it detects that element clickable. On the other hand too short timeouts will cause timeout exceptions in many cases if the web page had not complete loading in that limited time period
2)

```
try:
    while (element.is_enabled()):
        element.click()
```

I'm not sure it's a good practice to click on the same element with infinite loop while clicks are performed with a very short delays, actually kind of bombing that element maybe thousands times in a second...